# Add padding/insets to UIImage as background of UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitextfield

I want to have the triangle on the right side of the textfield with a little padding, currently it is right at the border:

[image]

My code:

```swift
class Textfield: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

func setup() {
    let background = UIImage(systemName: "arrowtriangle.down.fill")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: background)

    imageView.tintColor = .label
    self.rightViewMode = .always
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    self.rightView = imageView
}
}
```

How can I add insets so the triangle is a little bit more left?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the text fields methods. Like this

```
class Textfield: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBInspectable var leftPadding : CGFloat = 0
    @IBInspectable var rightPadding : CGFloat = 10
    
    private var padding: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets()
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: leftPadding, bottom: 0, right: rightPadding)
        
        setup()
    }
    
    func setup() {
        let background = UIImage(systemName: "arrowtriangle.down.fill")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: background)
        
        imageView.tintColor = .label
        self.rightViewMode = .always
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.rightView = imageView
    }
    
    override open func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
    }
    
    override open func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
    }
    
    override open func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
    }
    
    override func rightViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: bounds.width - 30, y: 0, width: 20 , height: bounds.height)
    }
    
    override func leftViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: 20 , height: bounds.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Raja. I already had the first 3 overrides, seemed to have missed the rightview rect overwrites.

Comment: Before your edit of rightViewRect it worked, something broke after the edit

Comment: @ffritz undo my ans ;)