# How to add space and resize image for rightView of UITextField

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextfield

I need to make this kind of text fields but I don't know how can I make spacing for rightView.

[image]

Here is a code where I'm trying to set rightView image

```
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: -10, y: -10, width: 22, height: 22))
    imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: systemName)
    self.rightView = imageView
    self.rightViewMode = .always
```

I've tried to play around CGRect coordinates and size but my rightView looks same every time

Here is how my UITextField looks now

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add padding/insets to UIImage as background of UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66117881/add-padding-insets-to-uiimage-as-background-of-uitextfield)

Answer (score 1):

```
`    public override func rightViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return CGRect(x: bounds.width - 30, y: 0, width: 30 , height: bounds.height)
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`parentView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 8)`

on `parent` textview.